# Jquery Datepicker UI jumps to min-Date when reaching max-Date. Solution?

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using JQuery Datepicker on a jsp Site. When a Datefield is in focus I add a Datepicker to that Field and set the Min and Max Date like so.

```
$(document).on('focus', '.date', function(){
    $(this).datepicker("destroy");
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
        minDate: new Date($("#minDate").text()),
        maxDate: new Date($("#maxDate").text())
    });
});
```

The Values of "#minDate" and "#maxDate" are strings in the Format "yyyy-MM-dd".
Now let's assume, that the min-Date is "2018-05-01" and the max-Date is "2018-07-30". When I focus on the Datefield and slide thru the months, as soon as I reach the last month (July) then the Datepicker jumps back to the first Month (May).
I tested this in Firefox 60.0.1 and Internet Explorer 11 (Version 11-431.16299.0).
Does anyone has a clue why this is happening?

Comment: I've not seen this behaviour, but it's very odd to define the datepicker on the element when it has focus. The plugin is intended to be instantiated once only, when the element loads. It may be the late, or repeated, instantiations which cause your problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for your tipp. The problem was that several inputs recived the same ID form the datepicker plugin.